# Include CSV or XLXS file for selenium

Tags: java, csv, selenium

I'm trying to copy a value from a row on a csv or xlxs file and paste it into a textfield on firefox and do some action and loop this until the end of the csv file.

After few research I discovered Selenium for firefox to automatize tasks.

Does someone have an idea of how the implementation will be or help me writing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/ Try something and come up with specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a csv parser like [CsvReader](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html) . You can use the following code as a starting point and build up on it. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

```
public String getValue(String fileName, String rowNum, int colHeader)
    {
        String returnVal = null;
        String relativePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String csvPath = relativePath + "\\src\\main\\resources\\CSV\\" + fileName + ".csv" ;
        CsvReader r;
        try {
            r = new CsvReader(csvPath);
            while(r.readRecord())
            {
                String row = r.get(0);
                if(row.equalsIgnoreCase(rowNum) )
                {
                    returnVal = r.get(colHeader);
                    break;
                }
            }
            r.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnVal;

    }
```